# PHP web scraper

Tags: php

estoy tratando de tomar los precios de los productos que estan dentro del link que estoy trantado correr. El problema es que la pagina web no me deja entrar a tomar la informacion. El codigo que tengo ahorita es:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Pantry/Canned-%26-Jarred/Broth/plp/RCSS001008003013?productBrand=Campbell%27s';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//follow HTTP 3xx redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//automatically update the referer header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

//accept the responce after the execution
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//don't verify the peer's SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//set the browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

//executes given cURL session.
$html = curl_exec($ch);

//disable libxml errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

//closes Curl session, & frees up the associated memory
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas entrar con una ip de canada, el sitio filtra si sos de canada o no. Fijate si podes usar una VPN o un proxy de ese país.